# I know the typeof(T) but the compiler doesn't. How to fix?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to write a method like this:

```
public static T Test<T>()
{
  if (typeof(T)==typeof(string))
     return "1241";

  // do something else
}
```

but I can't seem to figure out how to pull it off.  I want to return values depending on the type of T that the method was invoked with. I need to return strings, int's, custom classes, List  etc.

The actual usecase is some custom serialization code where it is essential that the deserializing code knows the type of the object it should produce.

Clarification:
the example above gives the following error:
Cannot convert string to type T

The ideal solution would work on value types and reference types, and would not include a dummy parameter for overload resolution.

I'm starting to doubt if that ideal solution exists though.

Thanks, Lucas

Comment: typeof(T) ought to work. Which error message does the compiler issue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The intermediate cast to `object` isn't ideal, but something like this should do the trick:

```
public static T Test<T>()
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
        return (T)(object)"1241";

    // do something else
}
```

Comment: Ah crap, I just said that too!  :)

Answer (score 6):

You have to cast the return value to T, e.g. something like this for reference types:

```
public static T Test<T>() where T : class
{
  if (typeof(T)==typeof(string))
     return "1241" as T;

  return default(T);
}
```

Comment: Compiler says: Cannot convert type 'string' to T

Comment: Sorry, I updated the sample. Note the "where T : class" part.

Comment: only problem now is T must be a class, so will not work for int, long, etc.

Comment: cant you do... where T: class, struct

Comment: @Chalkey: No, you can't. The compiler will complain that "The 'class' or 'struct' constraint must come before any other constraints".

Comment: @user59808: `int` and `Int32` are **exactly** the same. They're both `struct`s.

Answer (score 5):

**Beware**! The solution below does **not** work (verified using the Mono `gmcs` C# compiler).

However, it *should* work by my reading of the C# standard, since the overload resolution should favour the non-generic version of the method when possible. The relevant section in ECMA-334 is 25.1.7: “Overloading in generic classes”. Furthermore, Eric Lippert seems to say so, too, in a [blog posting](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/21/in-foof-we-trust-a-dialogue.aspx).

Feedback would be appreciated: why doesn't this work as expected?

---

You have got unrelated types and unrelated behaviour: this code screams “*use overloading*!”

Generics would be appropriate for unrelated types, yet identical (or highly similar) behaviour.

Do this (complete test program to reproduce behaviour):

```
using System;

class TestClass {
    public static T Test<T>() {
        return TestWith(default(T));
        // do something else
    }

    public static string TestWith(string dummy) {
        // Used only for `string`.
        return "string";
    }

    public static T TestWith<T>(T dummy) {
        // Used for everything else.
        return dummy;
    }

    static void Main() {
        Console.WriteLine("Expected \"0\", got \"{0}\"", Test<int>());
        Console.WriteLine("Expected \"string\", got \"{0}\"", Test<string>());
    }
}
```

Compiled with `gmcs`, this yields:

```
Expected "0", got "0"
Expected "string", got ""
```

Here, the parameter serves only for the disambiguation of the overloaded call. Explicit generic parameters cannot be used here since one of the functions (the `string` specialization) isn't generic.

Comment: Test<string> still calls TestWith<T> rather than TestWith(string)

Comment: Patrick: damn. true. I was sure I had already used this. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what the problem is. Can you provide a program that actually compiles and shows output that you do not expect?

Comment: @Eric: please see my updated (complete) example. From my reading of the standard, and the passage in your blog posting, I'd expect the specialized `TestWith` to be called instead of the generic one. Clearly, that's not the case so I'm wondering if this is just a compiler error in the Mono compiler or if I didn't understand said passage.

Comment: Got it.  The behaviour you're seeing is correct. Overload resolution analysis always happens at compile time, and then the overload that was chosen is "baked in" to the generated generic code. When generic method Test<T>() is compiled, overload resolution does the best it possibly can with the information at its disposal, which is to pick the method that it knows will ALWAYS work -- TestWith<T>.  The compiler has no idea that in the future, some caller is going to have T be string. If you want it to pick the best method given _runtime_ information, "dynamic" in C# 4 will do that.

Comment: This is a pretty common misunderstanding. I'll do a blog post about it on July 6th.

Comment: Eric, thanks a lot for the explanation. Now I think about how generics are resolved in .NET, it's obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
public static T Test<T>() where T : class
{
  if (typeof(T) == typeof(string)) return "asdf" as T;  // do something else
  // do something else        
}
```

Comment: Do a hard cast "(T)" instead of using "as T". Then you can remove the where-clause.

Comment: @Jehof: but the code won't compile anymore. So no, don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use ChangeType?

```
public static T Test<T>()
{
    if (typeof(T)==typeof(string))
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType("1234", typeof(T), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    return default(T);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
public static T Test<T>()
{
  if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
     return (T)(object)"1241";    // this works.

    // do something else
}
```

Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: Please check Luke's answer, he came up with the same solution as you

Answer (score 0):

```
public static T Test<T>()
{
  if (typeof(T)==typeof(string))
     return (T)Convert.ChangeType("1241", typeof(T));

  return default(T);
}
```

I've not tested it though :-)