# c#: how to convert string to custom template type (i.e. implement "T convertTo<T>(string)")

Tags: c#

I want a function that can convert "string" to a given type T.
I.e. I want to implement such function:

```
T convertTo<T>(string stringToConvert)
```

T could be actually either simple type or enum, but i don't know how to check actual T type at runtime. I.e. I can't write something like that:

```
if (T instanceof MyEnum) { return MyEnum.Parse(stringToConvert); }
```

How can I implement my function then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), stringToConvert);
```

Comment: and if you would have checked the post date, you'll see that mine was posted a minute before DarkBobG's.

Comment: Oops, you're right! It still wouldn't hurt to have a non-duplicate answer.

Comment: I just edited my answer a couple of times as I used different variable names, that why mine is below his.

Comment: Still, there's plenty of room to improve your answer. For example, you can trivially make it work for any `enum` instead of just `MyEnum`.

Comment: this work for enums, but how to make function work for simple types? ("string" for example). upd: i found answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031794/i-know-the-typeoft-but-the-compiler-doesnt-how-to-fix

Answer (score 1):

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(MyEnum))
    return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), stringToConvert);
```

Answer (score 0):

finally I've implemented function this way:

```
private static T ConvertFromString<T>(string text)
    {
        if (typeof(Enum).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
        {
            try
            {
                return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), text);
            }
            catch (ArgumentException e)
            {
                return default(T);
            }
        }
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(text, typeof(T));
    }
```